# Session values shows the old values after checkout

Tags: magento

In checkout, `review.phtml` and another file I use some PHP sessions like

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setbgdiff($bgdiff);
```

to set the value, and

```
$bgdiff = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getbgdiff();
```

to get the value.

But after checkout, if I go the checkout with new articles, etc. again, the value is the OLD value from the checkout before.

After reloading the checkout page with F5, it shows the values correctly.

How can I fix this? Is this a Magento issue? How can I get the session up to date?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved once the magento cache is cleared. Hope this helps somebody